# Why can't I select one column from a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH1XU.png

I run the following MySQL code

```
select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
from Instructor i
where (i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o));
```

Which gives the desired output here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJZDF.png

How could I get just the salaries from this query?

I've tried

```
$MySQL:>select (i.Salary)
from (select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
from Instructor i
where (i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o)));
```

as well as trying to change the first select parameter to i1.Salary or just simply (Salary), but no matter what I do I just get a syntax error

```
SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorExceptio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you need a table alias after any subquery.  So the following should work:

```
select t.Salary
from (select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
      from Instructor i
      where (i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o))
     ) t;
```

Note the `t`.  This is a name for the subquery and is required by MySQL.  The name "t" is arbitrary.  You can give it any valid name.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll mark this as solved as soon as this lets me.